# Camera and microphone permission for command line util in Mojave

Tags: user-permissions, macos-mojave

I’m developing a command line utility which needs microphone and camera access but in Mojave the permission request is not requested.
I think the problem is due to the fact that for accessing this devices a bundle with an info.plist describing the need for device usage is needed.
Am I missing something or there is an alternative method?
I need to run command line util only on my mac, maybe in the background, no app store or enterprise distribution.